# Summing in data.table returns different values in R 3 vs 4

Tags: r, data.table

I am getting a weird summation problem when using data.table in R 4.0.2. When I group data by one column and sum the other (the `bar[,.(C = sum(B)), by = A]` line), I get some incorrect numbers. Here is a reprex where I only load data.table:

```
> library(data.table)
> bar <- data.table(data.frame("A" = as.character(c(1,2,3,2,3,2)), "B" = as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))))
> bar
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
3: 3 3
4: 2 4
5: 3 5
6: 2 6
> bar[,.(C = sum(B)), by = A]
   A  C
1: 1  2
2: 2 10
3: 3  8
> bar[A == 1, sum(B)]
[1] 1
> bar[A == 2, sum(B)]
[1] 12
> bar[A == 3, sum(B)]
[1] 8
> bar[,.(C = sum(as.integer(B))), by = A]
   A  C
1: 1  1
2: 2 12
3: 3  8
```

Yet, if I do this on R 3.6.3, everything works as I expect, and the problematic portion above now looks like:

```
> bar[,.(C = sum(B)), by = A]
   A  C
1: 1  1
2: 2 12
3: 3  8
```

And everything else is the same.

Did R 4.* change some method of how numerics are summed? Why is it fixed when I convert to integers first?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output in `packageVersion('data.table')
[1] ‘1.14.0’` and `R 4.1.0`

Comment: I am also on 1.14.0:

```packageVersion('data.table')```
[1] ‘1.14.0’

Comment: ok, then the only change is I am using `R 4.1.0`

Comment: Ya, I have another machine with 4.1.0 and I do not get the problem there either. The problem for me is that I do not have control over the R version on the server on which this code is run.

Comment: Can you suggest the administrators to update all servers with same version so as to avoid this issues.  Or may open in docker and install specific versions

Comment: I can't replicate this issue on R 3.6.1 + data.table 1.12.6; R 4.01 + data.table 1.13.0, or on R 4.10 + data.table 1.14.0. And I'm not installing a 4th instance of R to check further ;-)

Comment: Can you also reproduce this with `reprex::reprex()`, see https://reprex.tidyverse.org/